# Pagination is not showing in jQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using JQUERY DATATABLES in my project. I have added all the reference and followed all the steps specified in documentation. But I am not able to see the Pagination's. I can see table sorting but I can see pagination numbers.I feel its picking wrong jquery library. How can I know which jQuery its referring?

[image]

I have below reference in my project to the datatable.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I have below table data

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>

        </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Airi Satou</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am rendering datatable here

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        var localTable =$('#example').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 5,
            "bPaginate": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"

        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Check the syntax here http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html

Comment: Did you try looking at this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200305/jquery-datatable-pagination-not-appearing

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: I am using jQuery v1.11.1

Comment: Working fine with version 1.11.0 here http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/fnL0pe3q/1/

Comment: I am having Kendo UI, may be it's jquery is conflicting with this one.

Comment: You should use jQuery 1.8.3 or above. There is nothing wrong with your code, see http://jsfiddle.net/u9z6uj6m, so your problems must be caused by something else.

Comment: Thank all, issue resolved. it was because of conflicting jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html lang="en">   
<head>   
<meta charset="utf-8">   
<title>Example of Employee Table with twitter bootstrap</title>   
<meta name="description" content="Creating a Employee table with Twitter Bootstrap. Learn with example of a Employee Table with Twitter Bootstrap.">  
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">   
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>  
<body style="margin:20px auto">  
<div class="container">
<div class="row header" style="text-align:center;color:green">
<h3>Bootstrap Table With sorting,searching and paging using dataTable.js (Responsive)</h3>
</div>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped" >  
        <thead>  
          <tr>  
            <th>ENO</th>  
            <th>EMPName</th>  
            <th>Country</th>  
            <th>Salary</th>  
          </tr>  
        </thead>  
        <tbody>  
          <tr>  
            <td>001</td>  
            <td>Anusha</td>  
            <td>India</td>  
            <td>10000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>002</td>  
            <td>Charles</td>  
            <td>United Kingdom</td>  
            <td>28000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>003</td>  
            <td>Sravani</td>  
            <td>Australia</td>  
            <td>7000</td>  
          </tr>  
     <tr>  
            <td>004</td>  
            <td>Amar</td>  
            <td>India</td>  
            <td>18000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>005</td>  
            <td>Lakshmi</td>  
            <td>India</td>  
            <td>12000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>006</td>  
            <td>James</td>  
            <td>Canada</td>  
            <td>50000</td>  
          </tr>  
    
     <tr>  
            <td>007</td>  
            <td>Ronald</td>  
            <td>US</td>  
            <td>75000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>008</td>  
            <td>Mike</td>  
            <td>Belgium</td>  
            <td>100000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>009</td>  
            <td>Andrew</td>  
            <td>Argentina</td>  
            <td>45000</td>  
          </tr>  
    
      <tr>  
            <td>010</td>  
            <td>Stephen</td>  
            <td>Austria</td>  
            <td>30000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>011</td>  
            <td>Sara</td>  
            <td>China</td>  
            <td>750000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>012</td>  
            <td>JonRoot</td>  
            <td>Argentina</td>  
            <td>65000</td>  
          </tr>  
        </tbody>  
      </table>  
   </div>
</body>  
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').dataTable();
});
</script>
</html>
```